# how to inherit the values of a foreign key in MVC 5? Invalid column name 'student_student_name'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

I kept getting this error

> Invalid column name 'student_student_name'

Here is my class for my database context

```
  public class CSdbConnectionString : DbContext
    {
        public CSdbConnectionString()
        : base("CSdbConnectionString")
        { }

        public DbSet<appointment> appointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<faculty> faculties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sched> scheds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<student> students { get; set; }

    }
```

My appointment class needs to inherit the values of the foreign key faculty and student

```
 [Table("appointment")]
    public class appointment
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int appointment_id { get; set; }
        public string appointment_description { get; set; }
        public int student_id { get; set; }
        public int faculty_id { get; set; }

        public virtual student student { get; set; }
        public virtual faculty faculty { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my faculty class

```
  [Table("faculty")]
    public class faculty
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int faculty_id { get; set; }
        public string faculty_name { get; set; }

        public string faculty_lname { get; set; }

        public string faculty_email { get; set; }

        public string faculty_password { get; set; }

        public string faculty_dept { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my student class

```
[Table("student")]
    public class student
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string student_name { get; set; }

        public string student_lname { get; set; }

        public string student_email { get; set; }
        public string student_password { get; set; }

        public string student_number { get; set; }

        public string student_program { get; set; }
    }
```

The faculty class is working fine. I can inherit the values in my view

```
 @item.faculty.faculty_name
```

I also used `public virtual faculty faculty { get; set; }` in another class to inherit the faculty values and it worked fine. I did the same thing to inherit the values in student class and it kept saying invalid column name.

I've already searched many solution here in stackoverflow and what happen is it just keeps getting new errors.

I tried adding this to the parent class which will be the one inherited

```
public virtual ICollection<appointment> appointments { get; set; }
```

and added this code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
      modelBuilder.Entity<appointment>()
                 .HasRequired(c => c.student)
                  .WithMany(p => p.appointments)
                  .HasForeignKey(c => c.student_id);
            }
```

and still there are errors.

All I did for the faculty to be inherited was add this to the child class `public virtual faculty faculty { get; set; }` and now I am trying to do the same with student and I always have errors. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first thing: Your student class has a string as a PrimaryKey and your are mapping it to an int in your appointment class

> `public int student_id { get; set; }`

try to change it and see if it works.

Comment: damn! was having a hard time with this all day. programming really is one big haystack where you have to find the needle. Thank you sir! Hahaha simple mistake.